# Job Tracker and TaskTracker in Hadoop2.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I Installed Hadoop 2.4.X. As expected there is no JobTracker and TaskTracker. Its Yarn based. Is there any way to make it use old JobTracker and TaskTracker for MapReduce and not based on Yarn ?  In short can I make JT and TT daemons running on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no configuration file for map reduce in the 2.4.x installation even though there is a file called mapred-site.xml.template.Rename the file to mapred-site.xml and remember to set the property mapred.framework.name to classic to use the job tracker and tasktracker.Also the start scripts start-all.sh cannot be used as it executes the scripts start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh.You need to execute the script that starts jobtracker and tasktracker.

Comment: Thanks ! I made these changes and tried to start task tracker
./hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker
It saying its depreceated . Any thoughts how to run task tracker and Job Tracker in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

As described above, there is no Jobtracker and Tasktracer in Hadoop 2.0 (yarn). It's better to follow this instruction (http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html) to get the idea, and you will find the processes are as:

- 25578 ResourceManager
- 25411 SecondaryNameNode
- 447 Jps
- 29464 NameNode
- 25222 DataNode
- 25905 NodeManager